# Q-linear convergence rate

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have a question regarding the Q-linear convergence of sequences. I know that the definition is: $\exists \delta \in (0,1)$ such that
$$ \|x^{k+1}-x^\star\| \leq \delta \|x^{k}-x^\star\| ~(1)$$
In this case, we say that $x^k$ converges to $x^\star$ at a Q-linear rate $\delta$. Can I still say the same if I have:
$$ \|x^{k+1}-x^\star\| \leq \delta^k (\|x^{0}-x^\star\| + c) ~(2)$$
where $ c \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The second inequality only gives boundedness. It does not give convergence.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: I edited the post, how about Eq. (2) now, will this guarantee convergence at a linear rate?

Comment: @copper.hat: thanks for pointing that out, I edited the post.

Comment: The problem would be much easier with the definition using limits.